# Select query order by nvarchar(450) column challenge

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with columns `RowId` and `Comment` from which i'm selecting rows ordered by `RowId`, so far all is well.

But now i have a requirement to have comments with a particular text/string to always come after rows that do not contain that text/string irrespective of their `RowId`. I must admit its my first time to receive such a requirement.

**Sample Data** 
(table not formatted properly, 1-7 are RowId followed by a separator | & then the comment string value

**RowId | Comment**

1     | test comment here
   2 | test comment more here

3  | test xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyy

4  | this row must appear at the top because it does not contain the word

5  | this must also be above all rows that contain the word

6  | this one has the word test

7  | this has the word test also

In that sample data, i want all the comments with the word **test** to come after all the comments that do not contain the word **test**

So rows 4 & 5 must be returned by the select query before all the other rows that contain the word "test"

Any ideas how i can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a case statement to your `ORDER BY` clause (ascending).

```
CASE
    WHEN Comment LIKE '%test%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS OrderByColumn
```

Everything that does not contain the string will come first, everything else will come second. You'll want this to be the first item in your `ORDER BY`

A very basic version would be this;

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (RowID int, Comment nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO #TestData (RowID, Comment)
VALUES
 (1,'test comment here')
,(2,'test comment more here')
,(3,'test xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyy')
,(4,'this row must appear at the top because it does not contain the word')
,(5,'this must also be above all rows that contain the word')
,(6,'this one has the word test')
,(7,'this has the word test also')
```

Query

```
SELECT
     RowID
    ,Comment
FROM #TestData
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Comment LIKE '%test%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC
   ,RowID ASC
```

Result

```
RowID   Comment
4       this row must appear at the top because it does not contain the word
5       this must also be above all rows that contain the word
1       test comment here
2       test comment more here
3       test xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyy
6       this one has the word test
7       this has the word test also
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I am too stupid to understand why the rows with RowID 6 and 7 don't come at the end of the output. Both comments contain the word "test". And since 6>3, I'd expect that row after the row with RowID 3. What am I missing?

Comment: That's because I'm stupid and didn't include the RowID in the ORDER BY in sample output. I've updated the answer now :)